# Text in comments can get altered, so copying & pasting becomes unreliable

Tags: bug, comments

I noticed a bug where non-visible whitespace gets added to text in a comment; the unfortunate side effect is when someone copies a sample statement from the comment, it won't always work as expected. Here's a recent case that can be reproduced every time:

1. Go to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613551/combine-result-of-multiple-xpath-in-yql-queries#comment-62322430) in Chrome v50
2. Copy the complete SELECT statement and paste it into the [YQL Console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)
3. Click the Test button (with XML as the selected format)

Expected results: `<results>Combine result of multiple XPath in YQL queries</results>`. Actual results: `<results/>`.

The reason it's not working as expected is because there is some whitespace inserted between "combine-result-of-multiple-xpath" and "-in-yql-queries". One way to see this whitespace is by pasting the text into a text node of [KeyNote NF v1.7.9 Beta 6](https://github.com/dpradov/keynote-nf/releases).

To see this working properly, repeat steps 1-3 from above but instead of copying the sample SELECT statement from the comment, copy it from the RAW Paste Data of [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/T5K3ZnVN).

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 64 bit, Firefox 46.0.1.

Comment: @DavidPostill Please try with Chrome v51.

Comment: I don't have Chrome 51 installed. If **you** are seeing the problem with a particular combination of OS/Browser then please [edit] and add to your question.

Comment: Chrome 51 is currently the beta channel. Beta is not supported. "We support current and previous versions of all browsers with some reasonable amount of market share, but not beta or development versions." [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208)

Comment: Maybe also *don't* put so much code into a comment

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome stable (v50) and it has the same issue. I'll update the steps to reproduce to make it more clear.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is not relevant to whether this is a bug or not.

Comment: But it is relevant to whether it's a bug worth the time to fix or not

Comment: Well, there are many cases when you want to include a sample line of code but don't want to add it as part of a new answer. It's worth it to fix this because people copy the code expecting it to work and find that it doesn't work; then code copied from comments becomes unreliable, which is not something you want on a site that caters to solving problems.